# How to enable anti-aliasing when rendering WMF to BitMap in C#/WPF/WinForms?

Tags: c#, system.drawing, metafile, wmf, .emf

Why won't lines etc be anti-aliased when doing this?

```
using (var myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
myGraphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
myGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
myGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

myGraphics.Clear(backgroundColor);

myGraphics.EnumerateMetafile(m_metafile, new Point(0, 0), m_metafileDelegate);
}
```

The delegate function looks like this:

```
private bool MetafileCallback(EmfPlusRecordType recordType, int flags, int dataSize, IntPtr data, PlayRecordCallback callbackData)
{
        byte[] dataArray = null;
        if (data != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // Copy the unmanaged record to a managed byte buffer 
            // that can be used by PlayRecord.
            dataArray = new byte[dataSize];
            Marshal.Copy(data, dataArray, 0, dataSize);
        }

        m_metafile.PlayRecord(recordType, flags, dataSize, dataArray);

        return true;
}
```

Do I need to override PlayRecord for a specific type to get anti-aliasing here?

The WMFs come from AutoCAD, if that's any help.

Comment: How is this related to WPF? `Graphics` is from `System.Drawing`, `Metafile` is from `System.Drawing.Image`, both namespaces of WinForms.

Comment: I'm using it in a WPF-application, but yeah, probably not related. I'll update the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in GDI+ using a WMF metafile, but it is with EMF Plus. You can convert to EMF Plus at the source, or on-the-fly with a poorly documented GDI+ method (see below).

GDI (not GDI+) renders the WMF file without using any of the compositing of the GDI+ Graphics object underlying it, it just is an enumeration of the direct GDI calls. [See this question for more, but all answers say about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783130/draw-emf-antialiased).

If you can convert the file to EMF Plus, this will use the GDI+ methods to render the content, and use the GDI+ compositing including anti-aliasing. If you're already using WPF, you might also consider exporting to XPS which WPF can render antialiased.

If you cannot convert at the source, you can call a GDI+ method from C#, but it is not elegant. You need to have access to the native handles used by the System.Drawing classes:

```
[DllImport("gdiplus.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern int GdipConvertToEmfPlus(HandleRef graphics,
                                                HandleRef metafile,
                                                out Boolean conversionSuccess,
                                                EmfType emfType,
                                                [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                                                String description,
                                                out IntPtr convertedMetafile);
```

You would use this with code similar to the following:

```
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
using (var metafile = Metafile.FromFile(@"drawing.wmf"))
using (var imageAttr = new ImageAttributes())
{
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

    var metafileHandleField = typeof(Metafile).GetField("nativeImage", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var imageAttributesHandleField = typeof(ImageAttributes).GetField("nativeImageAttributes", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var graphicsHandleProperty = typeof(Graphics).GetProperty("NativeGraphics", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var setNativeImage = typeof(Image).GetMethod("SetNativeImage", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    IntPtr mf = (IntPtr)metafileHandleField.GetValue(metafile);
    IntPtr ia = (IntPtr)imageAttributesHandleField.GetValue(imageAttr);
    IntPtr g = (IntPtr)graphicsHandleProperty.GetValue(graphics);

    Boolean isSuccess;
    IntPtr emfPlusHandle;
    var status = GdipConvertToEmfPlus(new HandleRef(graphics, g),
                                      new HandleRef(metafile, mf),
                                      out isSuccess,
                                      EmfType.EmfPlusOnly,
                                      "",
                                      out emfPlusHandle);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Can't convert");
    }

    using (var emfPlus = (Metafile)System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject(typeof(Metafile)))
    {
        setNativeImage.Invoke(emfPlus, new object[] { emfPlusHandle });

        // use EnumerateMetafile on emfPlus as per your example code or save it:
        emfPlus.Save(@"drawing.emf");
    }
}
```

[Here's a working example for LinqPad](http://share.linqpad.net/mwli2t.linq). It converts a WMF file (drawing.wmf) to an EMF Plus metafile, and displays it in the results panel.

WMF file in Paint:
[image: WMF file with no anti-aliasing]

Converted EMF+ file in Paint:
[image: EMF+ file with anti-aliasing]

---

For the sake of completeness, the above `GdipConvertToEmfPlus` method is part of what is known as the "[flat API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533969(v=vs.85).aspx)" of GDI+. Its original purpose was to serve only the GDI+ C++ classes. The C++ API which uses this method is called [`Metafile.ConvertToEmfPlus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535281.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! I can't really do much about the source of the WMF (AutoCAD LT), so a bit of nativeness is fine in this case. I'll give it a try and get back if it works, which it looks like it should (given my limited WMF/EMF/GDI+ experience).   (I figured the GDI functions would support some global "AntiAlias" flag and I've just missed which one.)

Comment: I'nm not getting there. (this, g) should be (graphics, g), right? Then I get isSuccess=true, but Metafile constructor fails with "generic error System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+." Also, imageAttr doesn't seem to be used at all?

Comment: You're right, the code isn't ready to use, and assumes you may have an ImageAttributes, which you may not. Do you have a WMF you can share to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Updated code to provide a working example. There were some problems using the Metafile constructor, so we need to call the `SetNativeHandle` directly in a notably crude, but effective, manner.

Comment: Thanks! Very much appreciated! SetNativeHandle did the trick. I really have to dig into how that works sometime. (Btw, imageAttribute / ia is not used in  your code, and it works fine by removing all related calls.)  (Also, thanks for opening me to the world of LinqPad ;-)

Comment: Ouch. I'm not getting the entire WMF, just 1/4 of it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071340/how-to-convert-wmf-to-emf-with-gdipconverttoemfplus-without-losing-three-quarte

Comment: When I run this, the result of emfPlus.Save(@"drawing.emf") is actually a PNG file, not an EMF+, so it doesn't scale well.

Comment: @logicnet.dk Unfortunately, you cannot save EMF files that way: "When you use the Save method to save a graphic image as a Windows Metafile Format (WMF) or Enhanced Metafile Format (EMF) file, the resulting file is saved as a Portable Network Graphics (PNG) file instead. This behavior occurs because the GDI+ component of the .NET Framework does not have an encoder that you can use to save files as .wmf or .emf files." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/system.drawing.imaging.metafile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Note that if your goal is to save the resulting EMF+ to file, simply use `GdipConvertToEmfPlusToFile` instead. You won't need `SetNativeImage` at all.

Comment: Output file `drawing.emf` it is `PNG`